# jQuery Accordion if hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am trying to make a accordion, and I want the H4 element with the class current-category to be expanded first.

My code:

```
$(function() {
     $( "#category-accordion" ).accordion();
     if ($('h4').hasClass("current-category")) {
        $( "#category-accordion" ).accordion("activate", $('.current-category')); }
});
```

And yes I am a noob.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`activate` is an event *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) which gets triggered when a panel has been activated. I believe you want to use the [`active` option *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active), which takes the index of the element you want to be opened:

```
$("#category-accordion").accordion({
    active: $("#category-accordion > div").index($('h4.current-category').next())
});
```

I assume your HTML looks like:

```
<div id="category-accordion">
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <div>...</div>
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YwBu/)

---

The jQuery documentation usually contains enough information and examples to solve such problems.

Comment: @Felix-Kling Is it possible to make it expand only if hasClass, else collapse all? In the Demo you have, it works if the "h4.current-category" element exists.